# how to get server response of a POST api in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I am using mongodb to save the credentials from signup page. When tried to give credentials that already exists server shows a response - 'user already exits' this response was viewed in postman. I am able to get statusCode but I am unable to get the same response in flutter. below is my flutter code.

```
  Future<String> uploadImage(filename) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(serverReceiverPath));
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', filename));
    var res = await request.send();
    print(res.statusCode);
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: I tried that as well but it showed "The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'StreamedResponse'"

Comment: what does status code print

Comment: statuscode is 200 & the data is posted to the data base as well, only issue is that I am unable to get the response. "res.body" did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the body response, use `res.stream.bytesToString()`

Complete code:

```
Future<String> uploadImage(filename) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(serverReceiverPath));
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', filename));
    var res = await request.send();
    print(res.statusCode); // status code

    var bodyResponse = await res.stream.bytesToString(); // response body
    print(bodyResponse);

    return null;
  }
```